# "invalid use of member" when trying to use my function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to solve a balanced parentheses problem, here in my code I'm trying to get 1 from a function is_empty() if top of my stack is empty but then  here i am stuck with this ugly error.

```
int is_Empty()
{
    int x=0;
    if (top==NULL)
    {
    x=1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

here is how i recive it

```
if (s1.is_Empty==1)
    {
        cout<<"matched"<<endl;
    }
```

my error log

```
bal.cpp:112:20: error: invalid use of member 'int stack::is_Empty()' (did you forget the '&' ?)        
             if (s1.is_Empty==1)
                 ~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error. It would also be helpful to know more about your `top` variable.

Comment: Why are you using an `int` where a `bool` would make more sense? `bool is_Empty() { return (top == NULL); }`

Comment: _@Pawan_ It looks like you  coud profit from reading a [good book about the basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (s1.is_Empty==1)
```

That is not how to call a function.

Here:

```
if (s1.is_Empty()==1)
```

You may wish to review your C++ book.

Comment: oh i get it,  the parentheses for function how silly of me , i feel like an idiot.

Comment: Yes, very silly. :)

Comment: Error description could also do a better job here though. I bet more people miss the `()` as a typo vs those who wanted to take the address or something that the diagnostics is saying is probably missing. I don't have a machine at hand just now but I think several languages would produce better/direct hints to just guide novices more ? It does mention invalid use of `is_Empty()` so that's a hint but it could ask if the user missed `()` later too.

Comment: @ustulation I agree.

Comment: anyways thanks for pointing out a silly error i'll  mind being more conscious about syntax then just getting carried away by the logic part ;)